# Is there a way to make this code concise?

Tags: c

I'm currently learning and practicing c, but the exercise I'm doing wants each functions to have 25 lines limit (without changing { } or using single-line if statements!)

Please help if there's a way to make this even shorter.

```
void    ft_write_file(void)
{
    char c;
    int fd;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if ((fd = open("write_exam", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 00777)) == -1)
    {
        ft_putstr("map error");
        return ;
    }
    while (read(0, &c, 1))
    {
        write(fd, &c, 1);
        if (c == '\n')
            break ;
        ft_allocate_g_var(i, c, 0);
        i++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (j < g_line)
    {
        while (read(0, &c, 1))
        {
            write(fd, &c, 1);
            if (c == '\n')
                break ;
        }
        j++;
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Note `while (read(0, &c, 1))` is wrong. (read() can return -1)

Comment: In c, you can basically write everything (with few exceptions) on one line, it's a bad practice, but if the only thing you want is low number of lines, you can write multiple 'lines' on one line.

Comment: Without making it too ugly you can collapse `int fd;int i;i = 0;` into `int fd, i = 0;`.

Comment: The phrase "each functions to have" strongly suggests that you may want to separate this function into multiple functions -- can you figure out a logical division of responsibilities between this function and new functions you'll create and call?

Comment: @wildplasser am I double checking for -1? what would be the correct form to use read?

Comment: @Ecto seems like I'll have to make do with this code. I don't see other way to make it shorter.. Thank you for letting me know though!

Comment: @nanofarad guess that's another way of doing so. think I can separate row/col function

Comment: You could also remove i++ and j++ and pass it into other statements: `ft_allocate_g_var(i++, c, 0);`  `while (j++ < g_line)`, but it's getting really ugly. Also, you can remove the {} for this while: `while (j < g_line)`

Comment: It seems like your function has 2 main components.  Put each in a subsidiary function.  3 small functions is better than 1 large function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, don't try to do two things in one function. And try to write your functions with sensible arguments instead of hard-coding their subjects.

For example, your function is really doing two things:

1. Finding and potentially creating the output file (with a hard-coded name).
2. Copying the entire contents of one stream (hard-coded to stdin) to another stream.

So you could break that down: (prototypes only)

```c
/* Returns fd or -1 on error */
int open_output(const char* name);

/* Returns number of bytes copied or -1 on error */
ssize_t copy_fd(int fd_dest, int fd_source);
```

Then your driver could be:

```c
ssize_t copy_stdin_to_file(const char *name)
{
  int fd = open_output(name);
  if (fd < 0)
  {
    ft_putstr("Could not open output file");
    return -1;
  }
  ssize_t copied = copy_fd(fd, 0);
  if (copied < 0) {
    ft_putstr("Could not write data.");
    return copied;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way would be to declare all the variables at the top in one line, for exemple :

char c; int fd; int i; i = 0;

Except from that I dont know, hope it can help a bit a least !